# Help for general transient analysis

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, transient

I need help with the circuit below.

[image]

I can't understant how to write:

$$v(\infty)=?$$
$$i(\infty)=?$$ (my suggestion is 0 for "i" because of capacitors will represent an open-circuit at infinity time)

I wrote 2 equations:

KCL:

$$i_{C_1} = \frac{i}{4} + i = \frac{5}{4} * i$$

KVL:

$$v_{C_2} + v_{R} + v_{C_1} = 0$$

$$\frac{1}{C_2} * \int i*dt + 2*i + \frac{1}{C_1} * \int \frac{5}{4} * i * dt = 0$$

$$\frac {\partial^2 v_{C_1}}{\partial dt^2} + 7.25 * \frac {\partial v_{C_1}}{\partial t} = 0$$

$$p_1 = 0, p_2 = -7.25$$

$$v_{C_2}(t) = A*e^0 + B*e^{-7.25*t}$$

How to move on to find A and B? I know that I found vC2, not vC1 as required and in addition without steady-state component.

KVL (rev. 2):

$$\frac{1}{C_2} * \int i*dt + v_{C_2}(0) + 2*i + \frac{1}{C_1} * \int \frac{5}{4} * i * dt + v(0^+) = 0$$

Comment: KVL is wrong; you haven't used the initial conditions; define the direction of iC1.

Comment: @Chu The direction of current through C1 was shown on updated image and KVL with initial conditions added at post bottom. How to solve vC2(0) an move on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By KVL: \$V_{C2}(0^+)=v(0^+)+2 \cdot i(0^+)=8 V\$

Consider the \$v\$ node:

looking to the left: \$v=4+\frac{5}{4C_1}\large\int\small  i\:dt\$

looking to the right: \$v=8-2i-\frac{1}{C_2}\large\int\small  i\:dt\$

Equating, differentiating, and re-arranging:

\$\large \frac{di}{dt}+\frac{\left(5C_2+4C_1\right)}{8C_1C_2} i=0 \$

solving:

\$i=2e^{\large -\frac{t}{\tau}}\$

where \$\tau=\frac{8C_1C_2}{\left(5C_2+4C_1\right)}=0.138\:s\$

As \$\small t\rightarrow \infty\$, each capacitor will be charged to \$\small 7.448\: V\$

Comment: May you check my KVL (rev. 2)?

Comment: May you write your version of KVL differential equation?

Comment: See addition to answer.

Comment: The answer from textbook for v(t) is 7.448 - 3.448*e^(-7.25*t). How you found tau?

Comment: Where I can find simple example how to solve dx/dt + kx = 0 equation?

Comment: Yes, that's the same as my answer if you find v from the i value. Also from the differential equation, the coefficient of i is 1/tau - classic 1st order differential equation! Look up 'integrating factor method' for 1st order ODE.

Comment: In your equation, above, e^(-7.25t)=0 for t=infinity, hence v=7.448 (as my answer).

Comment: The equation for v(t) from i(t) will be v(t)=1/C1*5/4*2*int(e^-t/0.138) = -3.45*e^(-7.25*t). To find v(inf) I need to take paste "inf" to v(t) and integrate from 0 to "inf" and add v(0) and I'll take 7.25V

Comment: v is given by \$v=4+\frac{5}{4C_1}\large\int\small  i\:dt\$ . Use my equation for i and integrate between 0 and infty

Comment: 7.25 = 1/0.138, i.e. 1/tau; it is NOT the final value of v. The final value of v is 7.45, or 7.448 to 3dp.

Comment: Oh, I write with error, it will give 7.45, thanks for check! The moment that unclear is how you find the sings for KVL components in "right" equation? I know that for it I must redraw the circuit and add voltage sources that represents initial voltages on capacitors and then go in direction of current and choose appropriate sign (first founded in path) for components but here I can't understand how it would be?

Comment: The initial voltage on C2 is 8V. \$i\$ is shown flowing out of C2, so it is assumed to be discharging and hence the voltage at any time is: \$v=8-\frac{1}{C_2}\large \int i\:dt\$. If the capacitor were assumed to be charging (\$i\$ flowing in), the voltage would be: \$v=8+\frac{1}{C_2}\large \int i\:dt\$

Comment: May that be seen using passive sign convention?

Comment: Just make sure all the currents satisfy KCL, then the algebra will sort out the actual current flows. In this question you are given two of the current directions and the only one you have to nominate is that flowing through C1 (which you've done with the block arrow)

Comment: May I find anywhere the schematic that shows how to interpret capacitor with initial voltage and where the signs of voltage drops is shown?

Comment: The rules for a capacitor are quite simple: (a) let the initial voltage on a capacitor plate be \$V_{C0}\$ (this will be relative to the other plate, and it doesn't matter whether it's positive or negative); (b) if the assumed direction of current is *towards* that plate then the voltage at any time is  \$v=V_{C0}+\frac{1}{C}\large \int i\:dt\$, if the assumed current is *away from* that plate, the voltage at any time is \$v=V_{C0}-\frac{1}{C}\large \int i\:dt\$. The analysis will tell you the actual direction of current by its sign.

Comment: Why you wrote -2*i in the second equation? If current "i" moves toward R then using passive sign convention the current enters the "+" node first and vR must be equal to +2*i, not -2*i.

Comment: right side of R is +

Comment: i.e, if right side of R is + then it's interpreted as voltage drop from + to - and 2*i is included with "-" sign in equation. So?

Comment: Known that no matter what current directions to choose. They must satisfy KCL and answer will be valid. Only sign may differ. In my task one direction "i" is set. Only iC1 direction I choose. But if no current directions given and I choose iC1 direction as I select previously but "i" select in opposite direction. KCL: -iC1+i/4-i=0, iC1=-3/4*i. KVL: V(left):V=4+1/C1*int(-3/4*i*dt), V(right):8+1/C2*int(i*dt)-2*i. Result:di/dt-i*[(3*C2+4*C1)/(8*C1*C2)]=0. Solving get another result and another tau. Why, if it's no difference what current directions to choose. Currents satisfy the KCL!

Comment: Dependent current source direction will reverse, and initial conditions will change. e.g. i(0+)=-2A. In other words, you've changed the problem. You would do better to understand the question you have been posed rather than create your own variation that differs from the original in important details.

Comment: May you recommend me any source - book/link that can help me to better understand of KCL/KVL applied to circuits with capacitors/inductors.

Comment: Any book that includes circuit theory. I won't give specific recommendations.